# Python - Não estou conseguindo somar os elementos lançados

Tags: python

tentei criar um programa para simular o registro de notas fiscais;

O programa deve ler número da nota, Produto, Valor da nota, Imposto.

O programa deve escrever o número da nota, produto, valor, valor do imposto e valor das notas somadas.

estou com dificuldade para encontrar a soma das notas cadastradas!!

```
 registro = list()
while True:
    nota = int(input('nota: '))
    produto = str(input('produto: '))
    valor = float(input('valor: '))
    imposto = float(input('imposto: '))
    vimposto = (imposto * valor)
    registro.append([nota, produto, valor, vimposto])
    res = str(input('Deseja registrar uma nova nota? [S/N] '))
    if res in 'Nn':
        break
print('{:<4}{:>10}{:>10}{:>10}'.format("Nota", "Produto", "Valor", "Imposto"))
print('_' * 40)
for i, a in enumerate(registro):
    print('{:<4}{:>10}{:>10}{:>10}'.format(a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3]))
print(sum(valor))
```

Obrigado.

Comment: @AugustoVasques Na verdade o Python 2 permite também a chamada utilizando os parênteses.

Comment: De qualquer forma removi a tag versionada por não se tratar se uma pergunta específica sobre versões, mas sim da linguagem em geral.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você tem uma lista "Pai' com listas "Filhas" dentro, ou seja, o Pai é a lista grande que contém todas as notas que são as filhas
, cada filha tem um valor, e você quer acessar esse valor utilizando-se da função 'sum()', isso funciona apenas  para listas que são
numéricas, ou seja não deve haver tipos numéricos e strings na mesma lista. Outro problema é que você esta tentando usar o sum() em uma lista
com sub listas, isso parece não funcionar, a não ser que você chame diretamente a sub lista "numérica e sem Strings" para aplicar o sum().

...Resumindo Situações...

Posso usar 'sum()' :

```
    lista_int = [1,2,3] // lista tipo int
    lista_float = [1.2, 1.5, 1.6] // lista tipo Float
    lista = [1, 2, 3.4, 4.5] /Lista com os dois tipos !
```

Não posso usar 'sum()' :

```
lista = ['Pedro', 12] //Lista numérica + strings

lista = [[12], [12]] // Situação onde tenho Sub listas dentro de uma lista maior !!! => Esse é um dos motivos para o erro.
```

...Apontando o que deve ser resolvido...

Retirei o *print(sum())* e o código rodou normalmente, então para que funcione com ele você vai precisar resolver o
seguinte.

1º  Como retirar o valor da sub lista e fazer a soma com 'sum()' ou sem 'sum()'. Ou apenas retirar o valor já fazendo a soma.

...Resolvendo o problema...

1ª Solução !

Você deve retirar o valor de cada sub lista (nota fiscal) com um loop for e joga em uma lista nova para que ai sim você consiga utilizar a função 'sum()', já que essa lista de valores teria apenas valores numéricos.

exemplo...

```
  soma_valores = list()

  for x in range(0, len(registro)):
    soma_valores.append(registro[x][2])      # x vai passar nota por nota a partir do 0, já o 2 é a posição do valor na nota do momento...
                                          #O valor é capturado e mandado para a lista do soma_valores               

  print(sum(soma_valores))
```

2ª Solução !

Você pode retirar esses valores e já fazer a soma utilizando uma variável com += para cada valor da sub lista(notas) que seja lido.

```
  var = 0

  for x in range(0, len(registro)):
    var += registro[x][2]      #Estou somando a variavel VAR com o valor da posição registro[x][2] da lista em questão e fazendo VAR
                            receber o valor dessa soma

  print(var)
```

+= Recebe a própria variável + o que você quiser, outro exemplo do mesmo sentido abaixo...
variavel = variavel + alguma coisa
ou

```
  x = 0

  x = x + 1

  print(x)
```

saída...   0

...Observações Finais...
Testei tudo e funcionou, eu não tenho certeza se você quer apenas o valor especifico do produto de cada
nota mas se for realmente apenas isso pode ir que dá certo. A primeira linha tem um erro de indentação,
acredito que foi durante a edição da questão, mas só pra avisar mesmo.

caso algum mal entendido ou problema com a resposta , comente.